# No Suitable application record were found, verify your BundleID is Correct

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3, app-store-connect, itunes

[image]
I have uploaded the app with the same bundleID so many times but now it gives me an error like this anyone helps me on this.

- My bundled is the same as my app created on iTunes connect.
- Also, Increased the build number by 1.

Thanks

Comment: Are you logged in with the correct account? Sometimes you get this if you setup a new app on the developer portal and then App Store Connect needs a few minutes to "understand" that there's a new app. Bundle ID's are also case sensitive. Are you 100% sure it's the exact bundle ID?

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure, the Same app is also uploaded by my team member with the same  bundleID.